# Horizontally display span text and input

Tags: html, css, inline

I want these two elements to be displayed inline.

Here is the code:

```
<span class="login">Login <i class="icon-user"></i></span>

<form action="#" class="search">
    <input type="search" class="search-input"/>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wkprG/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put the span inside the form

```
<form action="#" class="search">
   <span class="login">Login <i class="icon-user"></i></span>
   <input type="search" class="search-input"/>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wkprG/2/

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `float:left;` to the **login** class :

```
.login{
   float: left;
}
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkprG/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it in few ways. One of them is

```
.login, form.search{
    display:inline
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wkprG/6/